# Error building React Native app on Android with react-native-multiple-image-picker

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I was trying to implement an image gallery system in a app that i am building in React Native but when I installed the react-native-multiple-image-picker package and tried to run it it gave me this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Tibeo/node_modules/@baronha/react-native-multiple-image-picker/android/build.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Tibeo/node_modules/@baronha/react-native-multiple-image-picker/android/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 61
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
```

Do you have any idea how i can fix it?
P.S.
When I run it on ios, it works perfectly
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

based on reference from Tomerikoo developer. Here is the explanation:

1. Switch your Java version to a compatible Version. Major version 61 refers to Java Version 16.0.2 ([Java SE Development Kit 16.0.2](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk16-archive-downloads.html))
2. Then change your java jdk with the latest java jdk. To switch it you have to set your PATH. example on windows : [set JAVA_HOME in Windows 10](https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10) on MacOS : [Set $JAVA_HOME environment variable on macOS](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/#switch-between-different-jdk-versions)
3. Check your Gradle Version and update the gradle to make it compatible.
   In **android/build.gradle** you have to edit this line :

   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.y.z'

Change x.y.z with the version you want like 7.0.0 and then click Sync now

4. if the 3rd stage still shows an error message, you can use this 4th method. forget the 3rd way (restore as before) > Change the distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip inside the **android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** file and then click Sync now.

I hope this method can solve your problem